# Отключить drag & drop

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть скрипт выбора цвета. но выбор цвета в нем осуществляется переносом, а на устройствах ipad и прочих с ними яблоках перенос не работает. Подскажите как заточить под Apple или как сделать чтобы выбор был по клику?

Вот этот кусок кода добавляет drag&drop. Убрав его, цвет перестает выбираться, помогите дописать по клику чтобы выбирался цвет.

```
/* Включаем drug and drop */
            $('.img_fabric').draggable({
                helper : 'clone',
                opacity : 0.3
            });
            $('.basic_fabric').droppable({
                tolerance : 'intersect',
                accept : '.img_fabric',
                drop : function(event, ui) {
                    obj = $(ui.draggable).clone();
                    $(obj).css('height', $(this).height()-10);
                    $(obj).css('width', $(this).height()-10);
                    $(obj).css('marginLeft', '5px');
                    html = "<div ><span style='font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; display: block;'>"+$(obj).attr('id_title')+"</span><span style='font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-size: 14px; display: block;'>Основной цвет</span><span style='font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; display: block;'>Вариант: "+$(obj).attr('id_variant')+"</span><span style='font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; display: block;'>Категория: "+$(obj).attr('id_category')+"</span><span style='font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; display: block;'>Тип: "+$(obj).attr('id_type')+"</span></div>"

                    var id_cat_price = $(".fabric_prices[id_category = "+$(".companion_fabric .img_fabric").attr('id_category')+"]").attr('id_cat_price');
                    id_cat_price = (String(id_cat_price) == 'NaN')?0:id_cat_price;
                    var id_companion = parseFloat(id_cat_price);
                    var tov_price = $("#formated_price").text();
                    tov_price = tov_price.replace(" ", "");
                    tov_price = tov_price.replace(" р.", "");
                    tov_price2 = parseFloat(tov_price);
                    var this_price = parseFloat($(".fabric_prices[id_category = "+$(obj).attr('id_category')+"]").attr('id_cat_price'));
                    this_price = (String(this_price) == 'NaN')?0:this_price;
                    id_price_val = $(".fabric_prices[id_category = "+$(obj).attr('id_category')+"]").attr('id_price_val');
                    var real_price = tov_price2 + this_price;
                    if(String(id_companion) == 'NaN' || (real_price >= id_companion+tov_price2)){
                        $("#tov_real_price").html(real_price);
                        id_price_val_final = id_price_val;
                    }


                    $(this).html(obj);
                    $(this).html("<table style='display: inline-block; text-align: left; width: 265px; height: "+($(this).height()-10)+"'><tr><td>"+$(this).html()+"</td><td>"+html+"</td></tr></table>");

                }
            });
            $('.companion_fabric').droppable({
                tolerance : 'intersect',
                accept : '.img_fabric',
                drop : function(event, ui) {
                    obj = $(ui.draggable).clone();
                    $(obj).css('height', $(this).height()-10);
                    $(obj).css('width', $(this).height()-10);
                    $(obj).css('marginLeft', '5px');
                    html = "<div ><span style='font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; display: block;'>"+$(obj).attr('id_title')+"</span><span style='font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-size: 14px; display: block;'>Цвет фасадов</span><span style='font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; display: block;'>Вариант: "+$(obj).attr('id_variant')+"</span><span style='font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; display: block;'>Категория: "+$(obj).attr('id_category')+"</span><span style='font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; display: block;'>Тип: "+$(obj).attr('id_type')+"</span></div>"

                    var id_cat_price = $(".fabric_prices[id_category = "+$(".basic_fabric .img_fabric").attr('id_category')+"]").attr('id_cat_price');
                    id_cat_price = (String(id_cat_price) == 'NaN')?0:id_cat_price;
                    var id_basic =  parseFloat(id_cat_price);
                    var tov_price = $("#formated_price").text();
                    tov_price = tov_price.replace(" ", "");
                    tov_price = tov_price.replace(" р.", "");
                    tov_price2 = parseFloat(tov_price);
                    var this_price = parseFloat($(".fabric_prices[id_category = "+$(obj).attr('id_category')+"]").attr('id_cat_price'));
                    this_price = (String(this_price) == 'NaN')?0:this_price;
                    id_price_val = $(".fabric_prices[id_category = "+$(obj).attr('id_category')+"]").attr('id_price_val');
                    var real_price = tov_price2 + this_price;
                    if(String(id_basic) == 'NaN' || (real_price >= id_basic+tov_price2)){
                        $("#tov_real_price").html(real_price);
                        id_price_val_final = id_price_val;
                    }

                    $(this).html(obj);
                    $(this).html("<table style='display: inline-block; text-align: left; width: 265px; height: "+($(this).height()-10)+"'><tr><td>"+$(this).html()+"</td><td>"+html+"</td></tr></table>");

                }
            });
```

Comment: Добавь JQuery Touch Plugin и будет тебе счастье - все будет драгаться и на айпадах.

Comment: Дружище, подскажи подробнее, будь добр. Просто подключить плагин и все будет арбайтен?

Comment: Да. Включаешь его после JQ UI, но ДО первого использования JQ UI: http://touchpunch.furf.com/ (там и демо есть). После этого все элементы, которые раньше кликались и таскались, начинают работать и на тач-устройствах.